# How view change protocol works when we have exactly f faulty replicas in PBFT?

Tags: algorithm, blockchain, distributed-computing

I am considering a case say where we have 10 replicas i.e. 3f+1=10 meaning we can have 3 faulty replicas. Now, assume a scenario where primary is faulty and collude with other two faulty replicas and the remaining non-faulty replicas are in group of 4(G1)and 3(G2).
Now, the primary try to cheat by proposing  a client request differently to each non-faulty group say 0 to G1 and 1 to G2. In case of nodes in G1 the quorum 2f+1 can be reached 4(G1)+3(faulty) and thus can commit locally whereas it can’t happen for G2 as they have 3(G2)+3(faulty) i.e only 2f. Therefore, I am assuming G2 replicas will time-out and will initiate view-change process. But as per my understanding view-change will happen only when the new primary receives 2f+1(including self) view-change messages. But in this scenario the faulty might not send view-change which leave us with only G2(3) view change messages and G1 never ask for view change as they are already in quorum. This doesn’t satisfy the safety property. So, how actually PBFT solves this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering separate groups, then PBFT should be considered within these groups. If you have PBFT within 10 members, then this means that they all participate in the confirmation of EACH request.

Comment: I am assuming they all are participating together. Here, I have just divided to explain the scenario in which some nodes receiving 0 and some are receiving 1.

Comment: "In addition, if some replica misses messages that were discarded by all non-faulty replicas, it will need to be brought up to date by transferring all or a portion of the service state" (http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf, part 4.3)

Comment: Here, no message will be fully discarded by all non-faulty nodes as each non-faulty is receiving messages crafted by colluded group. I am not able to understand your suggest statement meaning  in this context.

Comment: PBFT defines the algorithm in which the nodes that receive the message determine its truth. But it does not define how the true message is delivered to those nodes that have not received it. This is provided by other mechanisms, such as the blockchain protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Primary can not send message in prepare phase. If a primary sends a prepare message anyway, all non-faulty replica will detect this as a faulty primary. They will initiate a view change immediately. Thus G1 will not reach commit local state.
For details, see here [Sawtooth PBFT Architecture](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/pbft/releases/latest/architecture.html#view-changing-mode-label).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for its answer since then. I would appreciate it if could tell what would happen if G1 has 5 and G2 has 2 replicas? I am considering commit local for G1 but how only G2 nodes would be able to do view-change?